# Is Share Extension appropriate for my case?

Tags: ios, swift3, ios8-share-extension, xcode8

I must do the following:

1. a user chooses a photo using the share functionality in the Photos app;
2. just like, eg., WhatsApp, the photo "reaches" the app;
3. the app does something with the photo;

The photo must NOT be uploaded instantly: it must receive the photo and store it (then, IF the user wants, he can upload the photo).

I was thinking to use *Share Extensions* when I red the following:

*Make sure that the Share extension point is appropriate for your purpose. The best Share extensions make it easy for users to share content with websites. If you want to create an extension that lets users perform a different task with their content or that gives users updates on information they care about, the Share extension point is not the right choice.*

(source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH12-SW1)

Problem is, now, I don't know anymore if *Share Extensions* can do what I need to do. Moreover, any online tutorial (and the original docs too) talks about a Share Extension Template that must have been removed from XCode 8.1 (I see everywhere screenshots of a template I can't use).

Comment: How I understand, `UIImagePickerController` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @shallowThought: no, because I'm NOT in the app, but outside the app. I'm in Photos and I want to open my app, not in my app trying to open a photo  :-)

Comment: Misunderstood than, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Share Extension was what I needed: it's absolutely up to you what to do with the file you are sharing. That is: you can freely create an App Group and store it to send it at a later time, no need for an instant upload. Moreover, you can change the appearance of the controls and perform validation of your content. So, in a smaller number of cases, share extension can be used with a slightly different purpose than intended.